# How to set java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true at runtime?

Tags: java, ipv6, broadcast, ipv4

I need to disable IPv6. For that the java documentation indicates setting jvm property `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

But I don't understand how to do it from the code itself.

Many forums demonstrated doing it from the command prompt, but I need to do it at runtime.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 to work around some bug you have in your code is just storing up trouble for the future. Fix the real issue now and save yourself a headache later.

Comment: I'd like to find out *why* you feel that you need to disable IPv6.  There may be a legitimate reason, but I've not seen one yet...

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Here you are: [authbind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/authbind.1.html) works only with IP4.

Comment: Another reason: Apache Ignite clusters may get partitioned unless this property is set: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");`

This is equivalent to passing it in the command line via `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: The broadcast address acquired is still 255.255.255.255

Comment: That seems pretty normal for IPv4. It's the standard 0.0.0.0 network broadcast address.

Comment: Are you sure this will work?. From looking at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/net/InetAddress.java#InetAddress.0preferIPv6Address) it seems to me that `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` is only read when the JVM is started and then never again. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Sorry. Forget that. I was mixing it up with `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` which is another property.

Comment: @Kal peterh is right, you must set it via command line argument, setting it via System.setProperty inside JVM will not work because it is read on JVM startup

Comment: The property is read from a static block in `InetAddress`. That block is executed when `InetAddress` is loaded and *not* on JVM startup. So if you set the property in a main method before using class `InetAddress`, it will work. Not the most reliable thing in the world of course.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach, if you're desperate and don't have access to (a) the code or (b) the command line, then you can use environment variables:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html.

Specifically for java web start set the environment variable:

JAVAWS_VM_ARGS

and for applets:

_JPI_VM_OPTIONS

e.g.

_JPI_VM_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Additionally, under Windows global options (for general Java applications) can be set in the Java   control plan page under the "Java" tab.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this very problem trying to send mail with javax.mail from a web application in a web server running Java 7.  Internal mail server destinations failed with "network unreachable", despite telnet and ping working from the same host, and while external mail servers worked.  I tried

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

in the code, but that failed.  So the parameter value was probably cached earlier by the system.  Setting the VM argument

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

in the web server startup script worked.

One further bit of evidence: in a very small targeted test program, setting the system property in the code *did* work. So the parameter is probably cached when the first Socket is used, probably not just as the JVM starts.

Answer (score 4):

well,

I used `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");` and it works from JAVA, but it doesn't work on JBOSS AS7.

Here is my work around solution,

Add the below line to the end of the file ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.conf.bat (just after `:JAVA_OPTS_SET` )

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Note: restart JBoss server

Answer (score 2):

you can set the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTS like as follows, which will be picked by JVM for any application.

> set JAVA_TOOL_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

You can set this from the command prompt or set in system environment variables, based on your need. Note that this will reflect into all the java applications that run in your machine, even if it's a java interpreter that you have in a private setup.

Answer (score 0):

System.setProperty is not working for applets. Because JVM already running before applet start. In this case we use applet parameters like this:

```
    deployJava.runApplet({
        id: 'MyApplet',
        code: 'com.mkysoft.myapplet.SomeClass',
        archive: 'com.mkysoft.myapplet.jar'
    }, {
        java_version: "1.6*", // Target version
        cache_option: "no",
        cache_archive: "",
        codebase_lookup: true,
        java_arguments: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
    },
       "1.6" // Minimum version
    );
```

You can find deployJava.js at https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js