# HttpServletRequest getRemoteAddr() returns ipv6 address, but unable to connect to it

Tags: java, spring-mvc, selenium, ip, remotewebdriver

I have a spring mvc web-app which basically runs selenium test on client machine.

I have created a selenium-hub and node in client system by using following commands -

```
>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role hub

>java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=D:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -timeout 20 -browserTimeout 60
```

my spring controller takes parameters for url and runs a selenium test using that parameter in client system using RemoteWebDriver

here is my spring controller-

```
@RequestMapping("/remote-app/{policyNumber}")
    public @ResponseBody String getOIPA(@PathVariable("policyNumber") String polNumber,HttpServletRequest request) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        String clientIp = request.getRemoteAddr();
        System.out.println("Input policy number : "+polNumber);
        System.out.println("Client IP : "+clientIp);
        oipaService.openOipaAddressScreenRemote(polNumber,clientIp);
        return "hello  "+polNumber+"   "+clientIp;
    }
```

here is my service method which runs the tests -

```
public void openOipaAddressScreenRemote(String policyNumber,String ip) throws MalformedURLException {

        System.out.println("Policy number input : "+policyNumber);
        String oipaURL = "https://mydom.com/PASJava_Term";
        String userName = "user";
        String password = "pwd";

        //-------------------

        String remoteUrlString = "http://"+ip+":4444/wd/hub";
        System.out.println(remoteUrlString);
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteUrlString),caps);


        //-------------------

        driver.get(oipaURL);}
```

It gives me desired results in my organization's client systems (PC), which connects to IPv4 address of client.

But the problem is, when I use Laptop clients in my organization, it returns me IPv6, which the app is not able to connect.

They are getting connected by laptop names, e.g. - **lt00123**.
i.e. selenium RemoteWebDriver is able to connect to `http://lt00123:4444/wd/hub`

How to identify the client address (ipv4 , or machine name) as required if it is at all possible.

EDIT: after using solution from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882357/how-to-set-java-net-preferipv4stack-true-at-runtime)  I solved the IPv6 problem. And from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/selenium-grid-with-example?edition=240484&utm_source=Daily%20Digest&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=dd%202016-11-16) I found that I need to set up hub at one machine (preferably in server location), and node at client machine using the hub. now my spring controller doesn't need to know client's address. It already knows the location of hub.

Comment: possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882357/how-to-set-java-net-preferipv4stack-true-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

The original problem's solution is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882357/how-to-set-java-net-preferipv4stack-true-at-runtime)

I just made little changes to my code -

Hub set up at server location-

```
>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

Node set up at client machine -

```
>java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=D:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub http://[server ip]:4444/grid/register -timeout 20 -browserTimeout 60
```

Controller -

```
   @RequestMapping("/remote-app/{policyNumber}")
        public @ResponseBody String getOIPA(@PathVariable("policyNumber") String polNumber) throws MalformedURLException
        {
            String clientIp = request.getRemoteAddr();
            System.out.println("Input policy number : "+polNumber);
            oipaService.openOipaAddressScreenRemote(polNumber);
            return "hello  "+polNumber;
        }
```

Service method -

```
public void openOipaAddressScreenRemote(String policyNumber) throws MalformedURLException {

        System.out.println("Policy number input : "+policyNumber);
        String oipaURL = "https://mydom.com/PASJava_Term";
        String userName = "user";
        String password = "pwd";

        //-------------------

        String remoteUrlString = "http://"+{server ip here}+":4444/wd/hub";
        System.out.println(remoteUrlString);
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteUrlString),caps);


        //-------------------

        driver.get(oipaURL);
}
```

Now my controller doesn't need to know client's ip. In stead of using one hub and one node in each client machine, I used one hub in server and one node in each client.

Now I can test from client side on client system on multiple clients.